# javascript module `gapi` is not work with Google Discovery Document List API value

Tags: web, google-api, frontend, google-fit, google-api-javascript-client

I'm currently using the javascript module `gapi` to develop a service using the`Google Fit` REST API.
According to the official documentation, `client.init()` in`gapi` need Discovery Docs information is needed.

https://developers.google.com/discovery/v1/reference/apis/list

When I searched the URL of Google Fit on the above site, it was output as `https://fitness.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest?version=v1`, so I wrote the following code.

```
gapi.client.init ({{
                apiKey: "********************************",
                clientId: "********************************",
                scope: "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/fitness.activity.read",
                discoveryDocs: ['https://fitness.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest?version=v1'],
            })
```

However, this code received the following error and ended prematurely.

```
<! DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = en>
  <meta charset = utf-8>
  <meta name = viewport content = "initial-scale = 1, minimum-scale = 1, width = device-width">
  <title> Error 404 (Not Found) !! 1 </ title>
  <style>
    * {margin: 0; padding: 0} html, code {font: 15px / 22px arial, sans-serif} html {background: #fff; color: # 222; padding: 15px} body {margin: 7% auto 0; max-width: 390px; min-height: 180px; padding: 30px 0 15px} *> body {background: url (//www.google.com/images/errors/robot.png) 100% 5px no-repeat; padding -right: 205px} p {margin: 11px 0 22px; overflow: hidden} ins {color: # 777; text-decoration: none} a img {border: 0} @media screen and (max-width: 772px) {body {background: none; margin-top: 0; max-width: none; padding-right: 0}} # logo {background: url (//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png ) no-repeat; margin-left: -5px} @media only screen and (min-resolution: 192dpi) {# logo {background: url (//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp. png) no-repeat 0% 0% / 100% 100%;-moz-border-image: url (//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) 0}} @media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {#logo {background: url (//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelog) o / 2x / googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat; -webkit-background-size: 100% 100%}} # logo {display: inline-block; height: 54px; width: 150px}
  </ style>
  <a href＝ / /www.google.com/> <span id = logo aria-label = Google> </ span> </a>
  <p> <b> 404. </ B> <ins> That ’s an error. </ Ins>
  <p> The requested URL <code> / $ discovery / rest </ code> was not found on this server. <ins> That ’s all we know. </ ins>
```

In the end, I found the code that worked correctly. That is the code below.

```
gapi.client.init({
                apiKey: "***********************",
                clientId: "***********************",
                scope: "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/fitness.activity.read",
                //discoveryDocs: ['https://fitness.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest?version=v1'],
                discoveryDocs: ['https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/fitness/v1/rest']
            }).
```

Looking at this, it seems that the value returned by the **Google Discovery Document List API** is incorrect. Why is this?

MyEnvironment:

- node v10.19.0
- gapi version 0.0.3

Comment: Why don't you post the solution you found as an answer to your question?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, English is not my native language. My question is "Why does Google Document Discovery API return the url of the data which is not available in gapi?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I should have read your question more carefully.